# Using onscreenclick to draw objects in specific parts of the screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have this code here that I just can't quite get to work correctly. As it sits currently, turtle isn't drawing anything at all despite no visible errors in the code. I am sure its something logical, but I can't find it. The code is supposed to draw its defined object, but only when the user clicks in a specific part of the screen. For example, if the user clicks in the top right of the screen, it will draw the sun. If they click in the top left of the screen, it will draw the clouds. I've attached an image showing what it is supposed to look like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/klWZT.png

Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
turtle.setup(575,575)
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(2)
pen.hideturtle()


def draw_sun(x,y):
    if x > 300 and y > 300:
        turtle.onscreenclick(draw_sun)
        pen.up()
        pen.setpos(x,y)
        pen.down()
        pen.fillcolor("yellow")
        pen.begin_fill()
        pen.circle(30)
        pen.end_fill()

def draw_cloud(x,y):
    if x > 200 and y > 300:
        turtle.onscreenclick(draw_cloud)
        pen.up()
        pen.setpos(x,y)
        pen.down()
        pen.fillcolor("blue")
        pen.begin_fill()
        pen.circle(15)
        pen.penup()
        pen.forward(20)
        pen.circle(20)
        pen.penup()
        pen.forward(20)
        pen.circle(15)
        pen.penup()
        pen.end_fill()

def draw_trees(x,y):
    if y > 100:
        turtle.onscreenclick(draw_trees)
        pen.up()
        pen.setpos(x,y)
        pen.down()
        pen.fillcolor("green")
        for i in range(3):
            pen.forward(50)
            pen.left(120)
        pen.end_fill()
        pen.up()
        pen.setpos(x,y)
        pen.down()
        pen.fillcolor("brown")
        for i in range(4):
            pen.forward(20)
            pen.left(90)
            pen.forward(50)
        pen.end_fill()




turtle.done()```
````

Comment: You are only calling `turtle.onscreenclick()` from within the functions you want `turtle.onscreenclick()` to call - so there's no possible way for them to be called at all.  You need to make that call at the top level of your code - and I'm pretty sure that you can only usefully call it once, so the function that is specified needs to make the decision of which of your three drawing actions to perform based on the coordinates it receives.

Comment: This was beyond helpful! Thank you!